# Is there any performance benefit of using Id field in Map instead of String in Apex Code

Tags: apex, salesforce-id

In my apex code I need to change data type of one variable from `Map<Id, List<CustomObject1>>` to `Map<String, List<CustomObject1>>`.
This change is required to full fill one requirement.

So, I want to know whether using String instead of Id in Map will have any performance issue when dealing with large amount of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no difference in performance, at least not anything you'd notice compared to the overall performance of dealing with large collections of data.